# Is it possible to detect key presses and releases on iPad Smart Keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, midi, audiokit

I am one of the developers of AudioKit Synth One, an open-source synthesizer for iPad, and someone left us a review with a request to implement playing of the synthesizer through the physical smart keyboard instead of the on screen keyboar.  A feature similar to Garageband or Logic Pro on the Mac's "Musical Typing".
[image: Musical Typing]

To do this I'd need to be able to respond to key presses and key releases. Does anyone know if this is currently possible with Apple's APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to key presses from external keyboard is possible by overriding `keyCommands` property of `UIResponder` (of which `UIViewController` is a subclass), however, you will not be able to detect distinct actions, like, *key down* or *key release*.

Override this property of the `UIViewController` that is supposed to catch this events

Swift:

```
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    return [
        UIKeyCommand(input: "Z",
                     modifierFlags: [],
                     action: #selector(didPressZ)),
        UIKeyCommand(input: "X",
                     modifierFlags: [],
                     action: #selector(didPressX))
        ] /// etc., return UIKeyCommand for each key you want to react to
}
```

Comment: I just implemented what you suggest and it does sort of work.  It tells me when a key was pressed.  But, it is unpredictable around key repeats when holding down keys, so I'll have to be clever about that I guess unless anyone knows of a backdoor to the keyboard status. Thanks!